# How can I measure the volume that a piece of text takes in a web browser screen with PHP (in server time)?

Tags: php, math, fonts

I need to store in a database pieces of text and the size of the layer that will wrap the text in the browser screen (I cannot build the layer in the client side - it is a requirement of the project). The whole piece of text must fit into the square layer properly. Users will be able to use different font size and font families from a small group of options and we'll know the selection at the time of computation.

Right now, I compute the layer volume based in the theory that every character size is its font-size pixels height and 50% of the font-size width. With the 50% value, I got the best approximation for the average cases, but it is still not a good solution because it cuts pieces of text or leaves too much blank space at the end. And it's even worst with some wider font-types.

Any idea on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Given how easy it is for users to override font choices in the browser, at best this would only be a "best guess" attempt, but you could use GD to draw the text and then compute a bounding box for it using [imagettfbbox()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php).

But this only supports simple text, so if you're doing "complicated" stuff with boldface/italics, variable sizes, etc.. then you're SOL for the most part.

Comment: We actually have very "complicated" text so this approach was not useful particularly for us.  But thanks a lot anyway.  Yours is a great approach for normal text.

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirements, the only way to do this 100% guaranteed is to:

**Render the image on the server** -- this can be to a normal image, to a vector format such as SVG, or even (more extreme) to Flash -- and **use the generated output on the client in some form which guarantees precise rendering** as *any CSS rendering/local-font issues may differ from the server-generated values and is thus unreliable!*

The exact dimensions of the box are thus known independent upon local font rendering issues as they depend only upon the servers "view".

Happy coding.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer before (I had a delivery date).  Thanks a lot! This was most useful. And an important part of the final solution.